# Average height of the particles in a monoatomic ideal gas when $T=0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, temperature, ideal-gas

Consider a classical ideal monoatomic gas (made of $N$ particles in the canonical ensemble) confined in a prism with infinite height. Consider the hamiltonian of a particle as

$$H = \dfrac{p^2}{2m} + \Phi(z)\quad, $$

where $\Phi(z) = \Phi_0 \log \left( 1 + \dfrac{z}{z_0} \right)$ is a potential depending on the height of the particle, $z$, with $z > 0$. What happens to the average value of height for a single particle when we approach the absolute zero? Will the particles be at $z \approx 0$, as it's the state that minimizes the potential, having then $\langle z \rangle \approx 0$?

Comment: are they bosons or fermions?

Comment: are you asking about the position of an individual atom?

Comment: Do you consider classical particles or quantum particles? What exactly is $\Phi(z)$?

Comment: Presumably this just asking for the ground state of particles in a potential $U(h) = mgh$. This seems a perfectly good question though I'm surprised it hasn't been asked before.

Comment: @JohnRennie I really don't see how to read the question like this. As far as I understand, OP wants to compute the average height of a particle in a system of $N$ particles as a function of temperature (and especially the zero-temperature limit).

Comment: @JohnRennie:  IIRC the solutions to the Schrödinger equation are [Airy functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) in this case. They were discussed in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/441689/what-are-the-energy-eigenvalues-of-a-particle-subject-to-the-potential-vx-mg) (and possibly others that I couldn't find quickly).

Comment: You still need to give more details. Do you consider $N$ particles in the canonical ensemble? If not, what else? What is the exact form of $\Phi(z)$, which could be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider a classical ideal monoatomic gas... [snip stuff about bosons]... Consider the hamiltonian of a particle as
> $$H = \dfrac{p^2}{2m} + \Phi(z)\quad, $$
> where $\Phi(z) = \Phi_0 \log \left( 1 + \dfrac{z}{z_0} \right)$ is a potential depending on the height of the particle, $z$.

> What happens to the average value of height for a single particle when we approach the absolute zero?

Starting from:
$$
\langle z \rangle =\frac{\int_0^\infty z e^{-\beta \Phi(z)}dz}{\int_0^\infty e^{-\beta \Phi(z)} dz} 
=
\frac{\int_0^\infty z\frac{1}{(1+\frac{z}{z_0})^{\beta \Phi_0}}dz}{\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+\frac{z}{z_0})^{\beta \Phi_0}} dz}\;,
$$
where $\beta = \frac{1}{kT}$.

Assuming that $\frac{\Phi_0}{kT}$ is very large compared to 1, we have:
$$
\langle z \rangle\sim z_0\frac{kT}{\Phi_0}\to 0
$$

> Will the particles be at $z \approx 0$, as it's the state that minimizes the potential, having then $\langle z \rangle \approx 0$?

Yes, assuming that we are limited to $z\ge 0$, we have $\langle z \rangle \to 0$.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I calculated. But I was asking for a more theoretical answer rather than a mathematical one. Is it right that when $T \to 0$ the system tries to minimize the potential, so $\Phi  \to 0$ and then $z \to 0$ as well?

Comment: I don't understand this answer. How do you obtain the form of $\langle z\rangle=\ldots$? Where does the many-particle ensemble $\rho$ enter? I don't think that it is that trivial to compute. Put differently, from $\rho$ you have to obtain the probability that a particle is, when measured, at a certain position $z$. From that you can compute $\langle z\rangle$. But this first step seems highly non-trivial for me right now. Note that we are dealing with indistinguishable $N$ bosons, not classical particles; so you do not actually answer the question, no?

Comment: If OP is interested in the classical case, which it seems since they accepted this answer, they should edit the question accordingly.

Comment: OP's first sentence begins with: "Consider a **classical** ideal monoatomic gas..." [Emphasis added.]

Comment: You''re right, I've missed that, sorry. But then the whole first sentence makes no sense, tho.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Yeah, that's why when I quoted OP's first sentence I snipped out part of it, since I wanted to try and answer a sensible question.